# Drawing a simple circle svg path using GSAP

Tags: animation, svg, draw, timeline, gsap

I currently have an SVG logo which contains a circular outline path around it. I'm intending to include a small intro animation to a website in which the outline draws around the logo before the page loads.

However, I'm a little confused. Do I require the drawSVG plugin to achieve this? I know that you have to pay for GSAP membership in order to obtain the plugin but as I only require a simple circular path to be drawn in my GSAP timeline, it feels like purchasing the membership would be overkill for what I need it for.

Can anybody help or offer any alternatives on how I can get this effect integrated into a GSAP timeline?

Comment: You don't need GSAP for a simple case like this. See https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow. But it was also answered over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/25624-animating-a-simple-path-outline-withing-a-gsap-timeline/)